# Getting VerifyError when adding try/catch block in bytecode through ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

In my Java agent I’m instrumenting classes using ASM. I'm trying to wrap particular methods with try/catch, plus tracing `methodEnter` and `methodExit`.

With `"-noverify"` the code works perfectly.

Without this option it fails with a `VerifyError` ("Expected stackmap frame at this location")–obviously because I don't call visitFrame.

I'm using `COMPUTE_MAXS` for `ClassWriter` and `EXPAND_FRAMES` for `ClassReader`. I can’t use `COMPUTE_FRAMES` because it will require all dependant classes to be loaded before instrumentation–which is not possible.

My current code:

```
// ...

@Override
protected void onMethodEnter() {
    visitLogMethodCallEntry();
}

@Override
public void visitCode() {
    super.visitCode();
    mv.visitLabel(startFinally);
}

@Override
public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
    Label handler = new Label();
    mv.visitTryCatchBlock(startFinally, handler, handler, null);
    mv.visitLabel(handler);
    visitLogMethodCallException();
    mv.visitInsn(ATHROW);
    mv.visitMaxs(maxStack, maxLocals);
}

@Override
protected void onMethodExit(int opcode) {
    if (opcode != ATHROW) {
        visitLogMethodCallExit();
    }
}

// ...
```

Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a first glance and without seeing complete code that cause issue, you are mixing up super.visitXX() and mv.visitXX() calls.

Also, dependent classes doesn't have to be loaded. You can provide your own implementation of [ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass()](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#getCommonSuperClass-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). For example, see [ClassWriterComputeFramesTest](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fasm%2Ftest%2Fconform%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2FClassWriterComputeFramesTest.java).

Comment: You're right about super.visitXX() and mv.visitXX() calls, but it isn't the cause of the problem. As to "dependent classes doesn't have to be loaded", I'm not sure at all that you're right here. If you use COMPUTE_MAXS, you'll need a proper implementation of ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(). I've seen ClassWriterComputeFramesTest and couldn't find there any helpful code.

Comment: What do you mean? There is an overwritten getCommonSuperClass() in there. Check it,but you may have to write your own class repository abstraction to introspect object hierarchies without reflection.

Comment: As for other issue, you will have to isolate it in a simple unit test. The snippet you posted is not complete.

Comment: Eugene, if you look at ClassWriterComputeFramesTest, you'll see that it refers to classLoader in getCommonSuperClass() to get instance of classes. This will not work in a Java agent because the classLoader hasn't yet loaded the classes.

Comment: Take a closer look. It uses ClassLoader to load resources and process these resources for type info, but it doesn't load classes.

Comment: Eugene, you were right. I've taken the ClassWriterComputeFramesTest's code and changed it to use the ClassLoader passed to ClassFileTransformer and it worked out. Thanks very much!